# Can the Wildfire Druid ability Blazing Revival prevent Instant Death due to massive damage or disintegrate?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, character-death

The 14th level Circle of Wildfire ability reads:

> If the spirit is within 120 feet of you when you are reduced to 0 hit points and thereby fall unconscious, you can cause the spirit to drop to 0 hit points. You then regain half your hit points and immediately rise to your feet.

The Instant Death rule states:

> Massive damage can kill you instantly. When damage reduces you to 0 hit points and there is damage remaining, you die if the remaining damage equals or exceeds your hit point maximum.

If a single attack did enough damage to cause Instant Death to the Wildfire druid, could Blazing Revival still keep them alive and restore them to half hitpoints, or does the Instant Death trigger before that is possible.

Along the same lines, what about Disintegrate? (I can move this to a separate question if that's preferred)

Admittedly, this scenario should be unlikely for a 14th level character unless they have a really bad constitution score, or take an absolutely massive crit.

Answer (score 16):

### No, your druid will die.

The text of Blazing Revival states:

> ...reduced to 0 hit points **and thereby fall unconscious**...

Emphasis mine.

Since massive damage states that you *instantly die*, you completely skip the unconscious part, just straight to death. Since you never fall unconscious, you cannot activate Blazing Revival.

The same goes for *[Disintegrate](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Disintegrate#content)* *. The spell says:

> If this damage reduces the target to 0 hit points, **it is disintegrated**. A disintegrated creature and everything it is wearing and carrying, except magic items, are reduced to a pile of fine gray dust.

Once again, we completely skip the step of unconsciousness, and go straight to a pile of ash.

* <sup>This has been updated via [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf#page=3) to read "The target is disintegrated if this damage leaves it with 0 hit points." The conclusion however does not change IMO, since you need to have 0 hit points to be knocked unconscious from damage, ergo you still skip the unconscious effects and go straight to a pile of ash. Refer to @Rluxx's answer for more on the errata.</sup>

Comment: Good answer but could you consider including the [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf#page=3) provided by Rluxx?

Answer (score 9):

### Yes and No

In regards to the Instant Death rule you would die.

But regarding the Disintegrate, an *[errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf#page=3)* came out that changed the spell where other effects are resolved first.

> Disintegrate (p. 233). The last sentence of the second paragraph now
> reads, “The target is disintegrated if
> this damage leaves it with 0 hit points.”

Mainly because of the Polymorph/Disintegrate power combo